# Vuejs clone object in script tag or inside instance e.g. data

Tags: vue.js

Wondering what is the best practice for such code here and what is the difference when cloning an object inside script tag or doing it in data property:

```
<script>
  import {cloneDeep} from "lodash";
  import {INVITE_USER_FORM_FIELDS} from './data';

  const FORM_FIELDS = cloneDeep(INVITE_USER_FORM_FIELDS);

  export default {
    name: "ModalInviteCreate",
    data() {
      return {
        FORM_FIELDS,
      };
    },
```

OR

```
<script>
  import {cloneDeep} from "lodash";
  import {INVITE_USER_FORM_FIELDS} from './data';

  export default {
    name: "ModalInviteCreate",
    data() {
      return {
        FORM_FIELDS: cloneDeep(INVITE_USER_FORM_FIELDS),
      };
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the `data` method will run every time you create a new instance of that component. If you never need to recompute a deep clone, then option 1 is preferable since the extra clones are a waste. If you're bothering to create a deep clone though, I'm guessing it's so your components can safely mutate the object without modifying the original. So option 2 is probably the best choice, otherwise all of the component instances would all share the same object.

Here's an example to illustrate, see the console.logs.

```js
const fakeDeepClone = name => { 
  console.log(`creating data for component ${name}`);
  return { name };
}

const aData = fakeDeepClone('a');

const componentA = {
  template: '<div>name: {{name}}</div>',
  data() {
    return aData
  }
}

const componentB = {
  template: '<div>name: {{name}}</div>',
  data() {
    return fakeDeepClone('b')
  }
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    componentA,
    componentB
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component-a></component-a>
  <component-a></component-a>
  <component-b></component-b>
  <component-b></component-b>
</div>
```